# Resolve NullPointerException problem in comparing elements of list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I want to resolve the following problem (shown by the java compiler) which comes out for the following action:
Unboxing may produce 'NullPointerException' for ... :

```
return list.stream().map(StatisticsUtils::getNumbers)  
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Long::valueOf)).stream()
    .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context is to what you are trying to achieve?. findFirst does give Optional<T> with which you can handle if value is present or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add a null-check in your stream, before unboxing:

```
...
.map(StatisticsUtils::getNumbers)  
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.max(Comparator.comparing(Long::valueOf))
...
```